# How to work with memory I did not allocate

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management

Is it possible in C# to work with memory I did not allocate? Or is it possible to change the size (but not allocated memory) of the already created array?

Here is my kind of solution. Is it the better way?

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class LengthOfArray
{
    public int Length;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
class MyArray
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public LengthOfArray LengthOfArray;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte[] Array = new byte[4];
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arr = new MyArray();
        arr.LengthOfArray.Length = 1024;
    }
}
```

And how best to do a similar effect with strings?

Comment: Not unless you use `unsafe`.  Your code will not affect the array at all; arrays are reference types.

Comment: The CLR exists to prevent you from doing such a thing.

Comment: It would probably help to know what you're actually trying to accomplish, because this seems like an extremely poor design choice ([XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: Well you can use dynamic arrays - such as Collection<T>; those types can be pre-allocated to some size - and they'll expand dynamically (on background, new Collection<T> is created of greater size + some size for future and old Collection<T> is copied over to new Collection<T>.

Comment: @dvnrrs I do not use this code in any of my projects, I want to learn the language features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
[FieldOffset(0)]
public byte[] Array = new byte[4];
```

This places a pointer to an array at offset zero. It does not place the 4 elements there.

[I cannot tell you what you should do because I don't know what you want to accomplish.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) If you *need* a variably-sized structure, allocate a chunk of bytes using any method you want (`Marshal.AllocHGlobal` or a fixed `byte[]`).